# Know if Backbone.Model.set changed/not-changed anything

Tags: events, backbone.js, model

Is it possible to know if `Backbone.Model.set()` has changed/not-changed anything without events if possible? Reason being: if I use events it will look like:

- listen to change:something

  - do something if value has changed
- model.set("something", "value")

But what if change does not happen? How do I know that? Also with event handlers, I need to remove them approperately. For example, if I do it this way, I need to remove the handler if a change does not happen

Comment: if the change didn't happen the event won't fire....I would stick with events, Backbone is an events driven library...give your use case if you want a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that hides Events, into a simple synchronous function that returns if set has an effect.

I choose to implement this in a different function name, but you can also override the default set behavior.

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
  setThatLetsYouKnow: function(key, value){
    var thisSetHasEffect = { flag: false};
    this.listenToOnce(this, "change", function(){ 
      thisSetHasEffect.flag = true;  
    });
    this.set(key, value);
    return thisSetHasEffect.flag;
  }
});
```

And the result is:

```
var m = new M();
m.setThatLetsYouKnow("key",2)// return true
m.setThatLetsYouKnow("key",2)// reutrn fasle
```

Of Course, you need to add support to all different kind of set argument, this is just the Idea.

Comment: @Jiew Meng - By the way, this implementation is based upon the current Backbone.js implementation of set listeners that happens in the same synchronous flow of the set (as opposed to setTimeout implementation)